If I allocate memory of size multiple pages, will the physical page frames be adjacent to each other?
I've read Linux device driver, Linux Kernel Devlopment and kernel.org and lwn articles but I'm still confused
If I request memory of sizes of multiple page_size,

Will the physical page frames assigned to said pages be physically adjacent?
Can the provided page frames be taken or reassigned?
Is it susceptible to Major Page Faults?
Will using vmalloc instead of kmalloc cause the page frames to be randomized?

Edit: In this case lets say I'm using kmalloc

"1. Will the physical page frames assigned to said pages be physically adjacent?" - Depends on chance and/or the method used to allocate the memory. Allocated memory that has pages which are physically contiguous is only assured when explicitly stated by the allocation method. Perhaps you need to study https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/core-api/memory-allocation.html and Contiguous memory allocation for drivers.

"If I request memory of sizes of multiple page_size" - You really need to specify how because there are countless ways for userspace to "request" memory from the kernel. If you mean by simple mmap then 1) no; 2) yes; 3) yes if they are swapped out; 4) not completely randomized, but most likely not contiguous, yes.

What if assign the memory by using kmalloc?

See https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/pull/190/merge/labs/memory_mapping.html#overview
